# T-SQL with Pivot or Unpivot actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[[image: MY PROBLEM1]

I have 7 tables has to be combined. I tried using T-SQL and UNPIVOT them with different ways. Could not figure out how to get my final result. Beg my pardon for excel sheet image. I do not know how to create tables with texts in stackoverflow.com

In the transcation table, **TYPE**s stands for sell and buy.
I need to sum all values from both card and cash **TRANSACTION_DETAIL** tables and list them as indexed to  **INFORMATION_ID** column which is inside **INFORMATION** table. Also by doing that i should be able to filter with between some dates.

It is kinda challenging for me. I have been trying to figure out how to do it so far 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: 'I do not know how to create tables with texts in stackoverflow.com' - run select queries against the tables then copy and paste result to question..

Comment: Build up your solution in smaller chunks. Start with 2 tables, then 3, then 4, etc. Ignore the `customer_table` because its values are not present in the expected result. Where does `pilot` in the expected result come from? Copy-paste the data in text format as instructed above please.

Comment: @jarlh I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: @Sander You are right i do not need to use `customer_table`. `pilot` was a mistake when i was visualing my data. Main point is; i should create query depends on "information_id" equals to "22".

Comment: Can you please brief about the relationships in between tables.

Comment: For example in CURRENCY table "ID" related to CASH_TRANSACTION_DETAIL table 'Curreny_ID'.